# JavaScript Image onload have no actual src property

Tags: javascript, image, onload, src

I have a simple example:

```
<head>
    <script>
        //
        function onLoadImgView() {
            //
            console.log(this.currentSrc);
        }

        //
        var i = 0;

        //
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
            //
            document.getElementById('imgElement').src = "img.jpg?" + i;
            //
            document.getElementById('imgElement').onload = onLoadImgView;
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <img id="imgElement" src="img.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="" />
</body>

</html>
```

I tried to get actual Image src property, but, I see it in log:

> "sitename.com/img.jpg?0"

Sometimes, I also get:

> "sitename.com/img.jpg?0"
>
> "sitename.com/img.jpg?0"

But how can I get a real log?

Because it should be like this:

> "sitename.com/img.jpg"
>
> "sitename.com/img.jpg?0"

Why does `src` and `currentSrc` not receive a valid file name in onload that can be loaded?

This a my question. Thanks.

P. S. I understand that I can save the src in DOMContentLoaded function and then return it in onload, but this is also not correct, because sometimes loading "img.jpg" is skipped, and immediately it loads "img.jpg?0".

Comment: Likely an issue with whether the requested image version is already in the browser cache or not ... In case it is, it might already be considered "fully loaded" when DOMContentLoaded fires, so the load event handler you are attaching to the image element at that time won't fire any more.

Comment: But it's really funny. Why is there no way to get the filename of the downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use window event listener and the `load` event. Something like this:

```js
var image = document.getElementById('imgElement');
var i = 0;

console.log(image.src);

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  image.src = image.src + '?' + i;
  console.log(image.src);
});
```

```html
<img id="imgElement" width="300px" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b0/Henri-Edmond_Cross_-_The_Evening_Air_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg">
```

Comment: The problem is that there is still no correct property in the onload. Workaround. If you are writing this code to a normal page, it has more errors, because, image don't can be set - DOM was not full create.